# Do we have any in-built keyword / demo file for converting json to xml and xml to json in karate framework?

Tags: karate

Payload input of type json or xml. Do we have any option / in-built keywords in Karate framework for converting the json to xml or xml to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should really read the documentation.

First read this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

If you have some very specific needs, refer to the `set` keyword and these examples: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature#L150

Comment: Thanks Peter. Will try this and post if we face any issues.

Comment: Hey Peter, do we have some active chat group like slack where we all can interact fast other than SO. Will be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas